# alternative of MPMediaPickerController for IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-4.1, mpmediapickercontroller

I have been searching since a week for that is there any library like `MPMediaPickerController` which can be used for IPhone (as  `MPMediaPickerController` works only for IPad). Kindly guide me that `MPMediaPickerController` works with Iphone too or not ? And if not then what is the alternative provided by apple for IPhone?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `MPMediaPickerController` only works on iPad?

Comment: I read on some forums, didnt remember their link right now, but i tried myself on xcode and I saw that when I select the project type for IPad, `MPMediaPickerController` works fine but whenever i select Iphone it doesn't. Is it because of SDK difference?

Comment: I've never used it, but it should definitely work on iPhone. The class has been available since iPhone OS 3.0 (3.2 is the first version to support the iPad).

Comment: I have the same thought but I think that I am facing this because of difference of SDKs. If I go with 3.2 SDKm then may be i would be able to use it on IPhone too, but unfortunately my app is on 4.1 SDK and I cant reverse it to 3.2, any recommendation?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it's something in your code that's not functioning correctly as I can categorically state that `MPMediaPickerController` works fine on the iPhone in every SDK version from 3.0 upwards.

Comment: Its amazing then :s can you tell me that which project type is recommended to use with `MPMediaPickerController` ??  I used windows based project type and MPMediaPickerController` not worked in that.

Comment: The project type doesn't matter, but you have to include the MediaPlayer framework.

Comment: I did include but still no effect. Even when I write `MPMediaPickerController *picker =`
    `[[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:` `MPMediaTypeMusic];` its not autocompleting them and also not changing their colors :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the apple's sample code. This is the link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845  In that code they are using MPMediaPickerController only. It is working properly on iPhone. You had made some minor mistake in your code

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already downloaded and ran it on simulator. If you see on Active Executables, it contains only Ipad 3.0 and that is the reason I was wondering that if it can work on Iphone or not.

Comment: It's just default setting done by Apple. I executed the same code on iPhone simulator 3.0 to 4.3. It is working perfectly well.

Comment: ok sir I will see it again and will get back to you shortly. Thanks a lot for your guidance.